# Webcomic (Keenspot?) about an amateur stage magician in a world where magic is real

Tags: story-identification, webcomics

This is one that popped into my head while reading another *story-identification* question. It was a webcomic that I read somewhere in the early 2010s. The setting was Victorian England, or an approximation thereof with the male main character being a stage magician (like in our world, using tricks to simulate magic) in a world where magic actually existed. I don't remember whether he couldn't use magic, or if he simply preferred stage magic. Anyhow, in the first arc of the story, he encounters a female bounty hunter — I remember she was shown to be a bit rough-and-tumble, might have smoked to a scandalous degree — and he winds up getting carried into her escapades. Because the world is so used to actual magic, his miscellaneous tricks often throw people off because they don't work in the way that people expect magic to work. I think she might have had a dog?

The color scheme tended towards browns with occasional bits of color. Artwork was non-realistic, rounded edges, Western style, not anime-styled, and I remember that the protagonist had a large rounded nose (not like comical clown-nose roundness, but rounder than a real-life nose). I think it may have run on Keenspot at some point, but I couldn't find it on their current list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is [Widdershins](http://www.widdershinscomic.com).

From the About page:

> Widdershins is a series of Victorian-era adventure stories, set in the fictional town of Widdershins, West Yorkshire- England’s magical epicentre, home to bounty hunters, failed wizards, stage magicians, and more, besides.

The stage magician with the round nose is [Sidney Malik](http://www.widdershinscomic.com/wdshn-character/sid/), and the smoking bounty hunter is [Harriet Barber](http://www.widdershinscomic.com/wdshn-character/harry/).